# How to turn a string of 1s and 0s to a signal for processing Fourier Transform?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

Given a binary sequence: 101101010101

How can you turn this into a signal to be processed by the SciPy Python library for Fourier Transform?

https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/

Comment: What does the binary sequence represent? What are you hoping to discover by applying a Fourier transform to it?

Comment: the binary sequence represents the occurrence of a signal at 1, and empty space at 0, we can assume 1 : 1 time units

Comment: typically you feed a floating point array into the Fourier Transform api call ...  additionally its assumed the signal represented by this floating point curve is periodic and the frequency resolution of the output array generated by the api call is uniquely driven by the size of the input array ...  more importantly a FFT call converts a time domain signal into its frequency domain representation ... sounds like your sequence of 0 and 1 is a  signal already in the frequency domain representation and you might think about implications of feeding your sequence into an inverse FFT call